# Text Classification using NLTK3 error?

Tags: python, text, classification, nltk

I'm working on Arabic text classification using NLTK3.. I got the following error ,can you please help me to figure out the bug

```
"calssifier =NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/classify/naivebayes.py", line 194, in train
    for fname, fval in featureset.items():
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'items'"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**train_set** is a string, when it should have been a dict.

Comment: can u give an example

Comment: The OP has set `train_set = “something”` instead of `train_set = { “items”: “something” }`. Trivial error.

Answer (score 0):

The error message

```
 'unicode' object has no attribute 'items'"
```

implies that `train_set` is a `unicode` when it should have been a dict-like
object with an `items` method.

To say more would require you posting a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonsrates the error.

See [chapter 6 of the NLTK book](http://nltk.org/book/ch06.html) for an example using

```
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. I followed the same example in ch6, I got accuracy 1.0 which is can'n't be . I have a different usecase , I have a training set as reviews each review has its aspects already. and I want to build a classifier that is able to determine aspects of test reviews . I will use Part of speech Tagging as a feature. I built the feature function ,but I can't understand how to put the feature into classifier? , I noticed test_set also should be formed as dict same as train_set!.

Comment: please give an example